# Why does the sbt tutorial fail on adding the plugin?

Tags: sbt

I'm working thru the sbt introductory tutorial at https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html and when I reload after the step "Add sbt-native-packager plugin" which adds a plugin, it fails, with many warnings and errors, to a prompt of "Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?"  At that point sbt has basically died.  I will append a full capture of the errors.

I believe I followed all instructions.  What is going wrong?

I have tried:

- Restarting sbt
- Undoing the latest code the tutorial asked for (plugins.sbt and changes in build.sbt) and restarting sbt.  Then sbt is live again, but of course as soon as I add the code back it dies again.
- Adding resolvers for other repos that I know of,

  - The built-in resolvers mentioned in https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html
  - resolvers += "apache-repo" at "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/typesafe/"
  - resolvers += "lightbend" at "https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/releases/"
  - resolvers += "lightbend" at "https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"
- Totally replacing the "resolvers" variable in case an early one was poisoning the process.
- Changing the requested version from "1.3.4" to other versions of sbt-native-
  packager that I know exist.  Basically the same story with different version numbers.

As I am new to Scala and sbt, I may be missing something elementary, but I'm just not seeing it.

Here is the complete error log:

```
[info] Loading settings for project foo-build-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/tehom/projects/ic-fab/foo-build/project
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.3.4 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.3.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.12_1.0/1.3.4/sbt-native-packager-1.3.4.pom
[error]   not found: /home/tehom/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:246)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$34(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:215)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:215)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:52)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:102)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:69)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:96)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:150)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:129)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:2947)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.3.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.12_1.0/1.3.4/sbt-native-packager-1.3.4.pom
[error]   not found: /home/tehom/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was going wrong - approximately, anyways. Sbt and Java underneath it seemed to have had outdated security certificates.  Odd, as I just installed it this week.

The command:

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

updated the relevant certificates and then it worked.